# Simple equation, but I don't get it

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't know how to do this simple equation, could you help me? thanks!

6x + 4   =  4 [ 2x -5 ( x -2 ) ]

6x +4 = 4  [ 2x -5x +10 ]

6x +4 = 8x -20x +40

+6x -8x +20x = -4 +40

18x  = 36

36:18 = 2

Thank you all!

Comment: it's a linear equation. just rearrange to get x = number

Comment: I don't really know why this question got downvoted... it is completely valid.

Comment: @recursiverecursion It was heavily edited and improved $2$ minutes ago - the downvotes were (apparently) all received before then.

Comment: oh, sorry, didn't realize that.

Comment: Also $36/22 = 18/11 \neq 1.6$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you solved $-5(x-2)$ wrong.
$$-5(x-2)$$
watch out for the minus(-) before the 5:
$$-5x + 10$$